# group actions on spheres

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-actions, geometric-topology, hopf-fibration

Let $\mathbb{Z}/2$ act on the $m$-sphere $S^m$ freely and properly discontinuously. If the action is not trivial, can we conclude that the action is homotopy equivalent to the antipodal action? That is, the following diagram

[image]
commutes up to homotopy?

Can we generalize this to $S^1$-actions on $S^{2m+1}$ and $S^3$-actions on $S^{4m+3}$? Is the uniqueness true?

Comment: Also, note that the properly discontinuous requirement is redundant there. Free action of finite groups on Hausdorff spaces is automatically properly discontinuous.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $\Bbb Z/2$ acts freely on $S^n$, then acting by the nontrivial element of $\Bbb Z/2$ one gets a map $f:S^n \to S^n$ which has no fixed point.

Thus, $f(x) \neq x$ for all $x \in S^n$. The homotopy $$F(x, t) = \frac{(1-t)x - tf(x)}{|(1-t)x - tf(x)|}$$

between $f$ and the antipodal map $-\text{id}$ is well-defined. Thus the map induced by that action is indeed homotopic to the antipodal map.

Comment: Does it then follow that the quotients of the actions are homotopy equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. For example your action could consist of a rotation by 180 degrees around some hyperplane. That is homotopic to the identity but not the antipodal map.

Comment: That's not a free action. For example if $m = 2$, this action must leave the anitpodal points fixed, hence is not free.

Comment: @BalarkaSen That requirement from the question is added after this answer was posted.